# How can I make my HTML5 website render in latest IE version AND be W3C Compliant?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility, w3c-validation, x-ua-compatible

Unfortunately I had the problem with my HTML5 website, where my Internet Explorer browser (I'm on version 11) decided it was the right thing to do to load the website in IE7 compatibility mode.

*Insert annoyed face*

Adding this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the website **does** make it work correctly in IE, **however** if you put the website through the W3C Validator, it throws this error at you:

> Line 6, Column 59: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv
>   on element meta.

I want to know if anyone knows if there's a way of having the best of both worlds?

Comment: That's super weird. IE11 should not try to load anything in compatibility mode by default. But hey, it's IE.

Comment: Apparently, IE (my version 11 at least) by default has "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" turned on. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was on a local website, I had to un-tick the *Display intranet sites in Compatibility View*:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> > Compatibility view settings

The other option I found which has helped for my published project was to add some code in web config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This is obviously IIS on Windows, but you can apparently [achieve this on Apache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2008/08/28/apache-httpd-configuration-for-ie7-standard-mode-rendering-in-ie8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late for a contribution, but maybe someone can use it. Based on the fact that `<meta http-equiv="..." content="...">` is used to simulate an HTTP response header (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)), if you have access to a scripting language like PHP, you could try something like this:

```
<?php

header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge');

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

...
```

That way, the server still sends the header, but it's not in the HTML5 code itself. I used this on my website and it validates correctly on the W3C validator. I'm not sure about it having the expected results with IE rendering. Maybe someone can give feedback. My experiments are not too conclusive. I did find some small differences between using the PHP header function and using the meta tag when I tested a page in http://netrenderer.com/.

Comment: After telling IE to stop being stupid with intranet sites, I found another post on SO that mentioned you could do it in the web.config: `<system.webServer>   <httpProtocol>   <customHeaders>   <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />   </customHeaders>   </httpProtocol>   </system.webServer>`